# How to get data in selfmade column of datagridview in c#

Tags: c#

I have one datagridview in which i create four columns
i want to get database data in these column which i create
i am using the following code by which datagridview get last row of database data.
For Example Id "1" has 3 rows of data in database datagridview get 3rd row data in all three rows.See the following picture of gridview result and database data                                                     [My Gridview result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgW14.jpg)   [My Database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb9BZ.jpg)

```
 cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from ReceiptVoucher where Rid='" + TxtSearch.Text + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dt.Rows.Count);

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {

                    MessageBox.Show("");
                    dr.Cells[1].Value = item["DrLedgerName"].ToString();
                    dr.Cells[2].Value = item["Amount"].ToString();
                    dr.Cells[3].Value = item["Narration"].ToString();
                    dr.Cells[0].Value = item["SNo"].ToString();
                }
            }
            cn.Close();
```

Comment: Use dataGridView1.DataSource = dt to fill DGV,You can use following to create a dictionary where SNo is the key and the datarow is the value:             Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> dict = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("SNo"), y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList()); Or a list of strings :  Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> dict = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("SNo"), y => y.ItemArray.Select(z => z.ToString()).ToList())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Please provide more info?  A select is always cmd.ExecuteQuery(); (not Non Query).

Comment: i have share both pics. database data and datagridview result

Comment: id 1 has 3 rows of data in database which i share in pic 2 i want data of id 1 in my datagridview. in my coding my datagridview get last  row of database data

Comment: Did you notice the SNo in one picture has a period and the other doesn't?

Comment: sorry i dont understand

Comment: The first link is showing as column name S.No while 2nd link SNo.

Comment: Sorry for late reply

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question.

Comment: my question was, I have create four column in datagridview                                                         1. Serial, 2. Account Name 3. Amount              4. Narration. I have to get data from database in these manually created column rather to get like i.e datagridview1.datasource = datatable

Comment: Datagridview should not add new column data should should show in manually created column.

Comment: this is the result I want

Comment: You have two choices : 1) Change the asterisk in the Select query to only get columns you need. 2) Get all the columns using an asterisk and then filter the results.  The filtering is easier using a DataTable then filtering the DGV.  Having a dictionary make it easier if you only need certain rows of the data.